# Some issue with webpack resolving

Tags: javascript, webpack

I trying to setup my small app using webpack. OS Debian. When I try to compile and build project by "webpack" I receive this:
http://pastebin.com/gpwkebuq
and I don't know why. File app.js exist in folder "frontend". I saw that this error met many peoples, solution for this task for them was different, but no one solves my problem

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
context: __dirname + '/frontend',
entry: {
    app: "./app"
},

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "[name].js",
},
watch: true,
watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 100
},

devtool: "cheap-inline-module-source-map",

plugins: [
],

module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel'
    }]
},

resolve: {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
},

resolveLoader: {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    moduleTemplates: ['*-loader', '*'],
    extensions: ['', '.js']
},
};
```

This is my package.json:
http://pastebin.com/pCSCm9VA
Structure of my project:

```
-anotherproj
   -frontend
       -app.js
       -login.js
   -node_modules
   -public
   -webpack.config.js
   -package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the entry to

```
entry: {
    app: "./app.js"
},
```

Comment: What about just `app.js`

Comment: This is doesn't works too. I just deleted this project and create new, there's all work and I don't know. Sometimes programming becomes magic